# Launch activity that resides in a separate library (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to start an Activity from an application that resides in an android library. I keep getting the following exception when I try to start the activity from application.

```
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  ... 11 more
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.smarttech.androidlibrary.LibraryActivity.LAUNCH }
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.smarttech.application.MainActivity.buttonLaunchActivity(MainActivity.java:25)
09-07 12:26:35.300: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  ... 14 more
```

I'm working in Eclipse, and I have created two projects - application and library.

Library is declared as an Android Library through Properties->Android->Is Library
Application references the library through Properties->Android->Add.

I followed the instructions for [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

LIBRARY:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smarttech.androidlibrary"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LibraryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.smarttech.androidlibrary.LibraryActivity.LAUNCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

APPLICATION:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smarttech.application"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.smarttech.androidlibrary.LibraryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.smarttech.androidlibrary.LibraryActivity.LAUNCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

--

```
package com.smarttech.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void buttonLaunchActivity(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.smarttech.androidlibrary.LibraryActivity.LAUNCH");
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
public void buttonLaunchActivity(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LibraryActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I thought it wasn't working because I didn't see my new activity appearing. But the debugger shows that the OnCreate function for LibraryActivity is being called. On to the next problem I go :)

Answer (score 0):

You still need to register the intent filter for the activity in your application manifest. Add that in and it should work:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.smarttech.androidlibrary.LibraryActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.smarttech.androidlibrary.LibraryActivity.LAUNCH" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: No luck. I'm still throwing the same exception.

Comment: @Nathanael You added this to your application (and not library) manifest?

Comment: Yes. I've added it to both manifests. I'll update my post to reflect this.